# Retrieving subscriber keys via SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to retrieve subscriber keys for a batch of email addresses I compiled after running the subscriber engagement report. We're aiming to target more engaged customers for our upcoming Memorial Day promotion. I have a data extension with email addresses listed but I'm running into difficulty setting up the SQL query to pull the corresponding subscriber keys. I've modeled my query based on a support article but keep getting this error message - Incorrect syntax near ''...

Any ideas on how to resolve this error message are much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there were a few syntax issues in your Query (also next time please put the code in a codeblock and not an image as images can be misleading in char as well as it makes it hard for us to copy/paste across to validate.)

- First, you were missing a comma after `l.listName` on line 2
- After your ON statement, you had `l.listName = '_listsubscribers'`

  - This is not connected to any statement which is tossing an error
  - This should not be in your ON or WHERE clauses either as no listName will be that value as its a data view

The below should work for your needs - but keep in mind this is matching email addresses to subkeys. If you have multiple subscribers with the same emails, this may not line up right and/or potentially cause mismatched data.

```sql
SELECT
l.ListName,
de.EmailAddress,
l.[Status]
FROM [Memorial Day Promo] de
JOIN [_listsubscribers] l
ON de.EmailAddress = l.EmailAddress
AND l.[Status] = 'active'
```

Comment: I'm very new to SQL query and this was my first post here, so apologies for any formatting issues with my initial post! Thank you so much for breaking down the code and identifying the syntax issues. The support doc they sent me seems misleading now based these corrections. Much appreciate the assistance!!